# Function that returns number of significant figures after decimal point in specific formatting

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

Wondering if anyone knows a function that would return the number of significant figures after a decimal point? And even further how to put that number in a specific formatting?

For example if the number was 27.9834 it would return 0.0001. Or if it was 2.1 it would return 0.1.

Comment: Your first question is a bit vague. If `x = 2 + 1/10` you might get `2.1` *displayed* in the cell, but the way base 2 vs base 10 numbers work, the actual number stored under the hood might be more like `2.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625`

Comment: Sorry about that! Should have clarified that I was referring to what is stored "under the hood" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this using a LEN and MATCH to get the number of decimal points, then its a simple "^" function to get the decimal place.

Assuming your number is in Cell A1:

```
=10^-(LEN(A1) - FIND(".",A1))
```

Just make sure you are showing the right number of significant digits in the result cell or it will just look like zero.

The LEN() counts the number of characters and then you subtract the number of characters from the left to where the decimal is. I think there is an upper limit on the number of decimals that excel can handle, but i don't recall what it is.

Comment: Should that be `..., FIND(".", A1&"."))` ?

Comment: Jeeped, you are right as that would correct any errors if the input was an integer.

Comment: just test this for `2`, and got the answer of 10.  Shouldn't the answer be 1?  Also if you measure something that you measured in say "mm" and was 1000 mm long but you are displaying in "m", so you have 1.000 and have it displaying 3 significant digits (since you measured in mm)  how to you catch the trailing zeros when its not text but a number cell set to display the appropriate number of 0?  I did note OP did not ask for the 1.000 case.

Comment: Is it possible to use this function on two cells and then select the smallest of the two? I was attempting to do this with =MIN(10^-(LEN(A1) - FIND(".",A1)), [10^-(LEN(B1) - FIND(".",B1))]) but Excel doesn't seem to like that.

Comment: Kelsey, it seems to work for me using the min. If you copied your exact formula from Excel into your comment, it is likely due to the use of square brackets in the second part of the MIN statement.

Comment: @KelseyMarkey if this got you the right solution, would you be so kind as to mark the answer correct? Trying to rack up some additional points. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another method might be,

```
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, POWER(10, -(ROW($1:$16)-1))/(TRUNC(A2, ROW($1:$16)-1)=A2), 1)
```

[image]